# Scanning a large number of documents for tens of words

Tags: java, regex, algorithm, matching, string-matching

I have a large number of documents (over a million) which I need to regularly scan and match to about  100 "multi-word keyword" (i.e not just keywords like "movies" but also "north american"). I have the following code which works fine with single words keywords (i.e "book"):

```
/** 
 * Scan a text for certain keywords
 * @param keywords the list of keywords we are searching for
 * @param text the text we will be scanning
 * @return a list of any keywords from the list which we could find in the text
 */
public static List<String> scanWords(List<String> keywords, String text) {

    // prepare the BreakIterator
    BreakIterator wb = BreakIterator.getWordInstance();
    wb.setText(text);

    List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();

    // iterate word by word
    int start = wb.first();
    for (int end = wb.next(); end != BreakIterator.DONE; start = end, end = wb.next()) {

        String word = text.substring(start, end);

        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(word) && keywords.contains(word)){

            // we have this word in our keywords so return it
            results.add(word);
        }
    }

    return results;
}
```

Note: I need this code to be as efficient as possible as the number of documents is very large.

My current code fails to find any of the 2 key-word keywords. Any idea on how to fix? I am also fine with a completely different approach.

Comment: Why don't you try [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/) for such a task?

Comment: Yes, it would probably be better to use an indexing system that maintains the files. Btw, what kind of text that you need a million files of them ? If each contain 10 words, that's 10 million words. Imagine the I/o just to open/close them.

Comment: I need to store only the found keywords in my db. Indexing is not the solution.

Comment: Does the set of documents changes over time, or the set of keywords, or both?

Comment: I am building an index of my keywords in the documents. Existing documents will largely keep the same keywords. New documents will be added regularly.

Comment: Without some sort of indexing method that reduces the search space on the document side. You can really only improve things on the keyword side, which is going to be massively less efficient. However, you can covert the list of keywords into a trie then scan the document while trying to find each word/phrase in the trie. This should reduce the runtime to something similar to using the same algorithm to search say 5-20 phrases rather than 100. So perhaps 5-20x improvement, not much.

Answer (score 3):

Scanning every dokument does not scale at all. Better index your document in [inverted index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index)
Or as in comment use Lucene.

Comment: Indexing is not appropriate for my task.

Answer (score -1):

I believe creating an instance of `Scanner` would work for this. The `Scanner` class has a method that allows you to search text for a pattern which would be the words in your case.

```
Scanner scanner=new Scanner(text);
while(scanner.hasNext()){
    scanner.findInLine(String pattern);
    scanner.next();
}
```

`Scanner` class is good for doing stuff like this, and I believe it would work fine for what you need it for.

Comment: The core problem is that he has to search for many different keywords/phrases in every document.  Are you suggesting he reset the Scanner and search the whole document once for each pattern?  You can't really know until you try, but I would be very surprised if it performed well enough.  And what are you doing with that `findInLine()` call?  That makes no sense to me.